# How to configure my VGN-CS320J multimedia keys?

Tags: settings, keyboard, vaio

I can't use it.
Today is my first day at Elementary OS.
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, buckle up your big boy pants because you are going balls deep today!

We get to play with the terminal. Here is a list of commands that will set you up.

`sudo apt-get update`

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

`sudo apt-get install software-properties-common`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:teejee2008/ppa`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install ukuu`

`sudo apt-get upgrade`

- Now go ahead and use UKUU to update the kernel to 4.11.3
- It will say that there are errors the first time you try this, ignore
  that.
- Reboot your computer.
- Go back to UKUU and reinstall 4.11.3 kernel
- If the install was successful, go ahead and restart your computer
  again.

Now run

`sudo apt-get purge ukuu`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get upgrade`

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get -f install`

`sudo apt-get install gcc-6 g++-6`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get upgrade`

- Now reboot your computer again for good measure.

When you computer has restarted go ahead and run

`sudo apt-get autoremove`

- Say yes to any prompts.
- Reboot your computer and now try your multimedia keys and possibly
  your video drivers.

I have to do this for my laptop and desktop for it to fully function. The 4.11.3 kernel is really good and has not given me issues.

So yeah, it seems like a lot, but it is not. Have confidence!